# Select data between two dates where a date field falls between the two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I've the following query and I encounter the error : not a valid month. Help please!

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE Field1 = '12345' AND
      TO_DATE('4/28/2014 12:00:00 AM') BETWEEN TO_DATE(DATE1) AND TO_DATE(DATE2);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please improve your question, what are Date1 and Date2? What the default date format of the RDBMS? If you don't know, maybe your problem is just pass the correct date mask to the TO_DATE function...

Comment: DATE1 and DATE2 are oracle timestamps and 2 columns of TABLE1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the format mask for the date conversion. It looks like your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is maybe `DD/MM/YYYY`, with or without a time part. You're passing the date in a different format. You should never rely on the NLS settings really, supply the format mask for [`TO_DATE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm) in the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Field1 = '12345'
AND TO_DATE('4/28/2014 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2;
```

I'm *assuming* that `DATE1` and `DATE2` are already of type `DATE`, in which case there is no need to call `TO_DATE`; all that will do is convert them to and back from a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, which is either pointless or will do the same as `TRUNC()`, depending on how that is set.

Of course, the date you're using here is at midnight, so specifying the time isn't adding anything; if you will never have a tie part then you could do either:

```
AND TO_DATE('4/28/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2;
```

or

```
AND DATE '2014-04-28' BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2;
```

If `field1` is numeric then you shouldn't have quotes around `12345` either, you're just adding an implicit `TO_NUMBER()`.

But if you're storing numbers and/or dates as strings, you should really think again. Hopefully that is not in fact what you're doing...

Comment: Superb! This query worked: SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Field1 = '12345'
AND TO_DATE('4/28/2014 12:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  BETWEEN DATE1 AND DATE2; Thank you very mych @Alex Poole

Comment: What if the time format is in PM? Is there a way to pass the format mask for both AM and PM?

Comment: @user1100941 - you can use `AM` or `PM` in the format model, whichever you prefer; and either will accept values as AM or PM. They don't restrict you to only having before-noon or after-noon values.

Answer (score 0):

Months for TO_DATE need to be two digits so you would need:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE Field1 = '12345' AND TO_DATE('04/28/2014 12:00:00 AM') BETWEEN     TO_DATE(DATE1) AND TO_DATE(DATE2);
```

Reference http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php for more info if you haven't already. Having a format mask could help define the string in case changes are made in the future.

Comment: Oracle is clever enough to add padding where needed. It's surprisingly flexible about date conversions, sometimes; `TO_DATE('Apr/28/2014', 'MM-DD-YYYY')` works, for example. Just missing a leading zero is certainly fine; there is no problem with `TO_DATE('4/28/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`, other than style *8-)